# Makefile with msys on Windows strange behaviour using the include directive (On linux works perfectly)

Tags: windows, makefile, msys

Problems using the **INCLUDE** directive inside a makefile using msys.

I added MSYS in PATH and is ok until here:

```
PS C:\Users\Roxanji> Get-Command make

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     make.exe                                           0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\msys\bin\make.exe


PS C:\Users\Roxanji> Get-Command bash

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     bash.exe                                           0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\msys\bin\bash.exe
```

Makefile example:

```
-include a1

a1:
    @echo something: > a1
    

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) a1
```

On Windows cmd/powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Roxanji\eclipse-workspace\prototype\tst> ls
  
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        15.11.2020     05:53             81 Makefile
   
PS C:\Users\Roxanji\eclipse-workspace\prototype\tst> make

make.exe": /c/Users/Roxanji/eclipse-workspace/prototype/tst/"C:/Program Files/msys/bin/make.exe": Command not found

PS C:\Users\Roxanji\eclipse-workspace\prototype\tst> ls
  
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        15.11.2020     06:03             11 a1
-a----        15.11.2020     05:53             81 Makefile
```

On Windows using bash from msys:

```
PS C:\Users\Roxanji\eclipse-workspace\prototype\tst> bash
bash.exe"-3.1$ pwd
/c/Users/Roxanji/eclipse-workspace/prototype/tst
bash.exe"-3.1$ ls
Makefile
bash.exe"-3.1$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `something'.
bash.exe"-3.1$ ls
Makefile  a1
bash.exe"-3.1$
```

**Facts using cmd/powershell:**

- The file 'a1' is generated.
- Command not found message.

**Facts using msys bash:**

- -The file 'a1' is generated.

What I think is going on?

- I see that there are some mixing of windows slash "\" and unix slash
  "/"
- I see that the make "location" seems different under bash from msys:

  ```
  bash.exe"-3.1$ which make
  /usr/bin/make.exe
  ```
- I see that also under msys/bash there is this message `make: Nothing to be done for 'something'`.

I **think** that when make hits `include` another make.exe is spawned to read this other file, but is called from within make, that has a different PATH for make, and this causes some problems.

Someone can give explanations about this phenomena??

Edit 1:
using powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Roxanji\eclipse-workspace\prototype\tst> make -np | grep MAKE_COMMAND
MAKE = $(MAKE_COMMAND)
MAKE_COMMAND := /c/Users/Roxanji/eclipse-workspace/prototype/tst/"C:/Program Files/msys/bin/make.exe"
```

Shouldn't the `MAKE_COMMAND` variable bee equal to just "make"?
like: `MAKE_COMMAND := make` ?

Edit 2:

I think the problem can be tracked down to the fact that I can't run msys.bat under C:\Program Files\ because apparently there is a space in "Program files"??

Comment: My experience says that if you wish to run make directly from Windows, you should use native build of make (no cygwin, no msys). This makes more predictable results.

Comment: @raspy Isn't C:\Program Files\msys\bin\make.exe a native build of make?

Comment: No. It's probably a MinGW build, using MinGW concepts. A native `make --version` should say something like `Built for Windows32`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the most reliable solution on Windows is a native Windows make build. I was able to run your `Makefile` directly from Powershell using such native build without any errors, regardless of `make` being located in a directory with space:

```
> ls

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          11/26/2020  4:11 PM             86 Makefile

> & 'C:\Program Files\make\make.exe'
make: Nothing to be done for 'something'.

> ls

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          11/26/2020  4:17 PM             13 a1
-a---          11/26/2020  4:11 PM             86 Makefile
```

`MAKE_COMMAND` also looks good:

```
> & 'C:\Program Files\make\make.exe' -np | ? { $_ -match "MAKE_COMMAND" }
MAKE = $(MAKE_COMMAND)
MAKE_COMMAND := C:/Program Files/make/make
```

All tests done with:

```
> & 'C:\Program Files\make\make.exe' --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Built directly from source using Visual Studio.